# How to use header while using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have my login page where i need to check whether that username and password exists in my database or not
So i have fired select query where username and password is entered by the user.
Now I want is when there are no rows in result that means Username or Password is incorrect.

This header method is not working.What i need to do?

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count==0)
{
echo "Login Failed: Please Try Again";
}
if($count==1)
{
header('Location:something.php');
}
```

Comment: check return data from ajax and redirect via js window.location

Answer (score 2):

You already have an ajax call. Use this function as a callback:

```
function success(message) {
    if (message === "success") {
        window.location.href = yourpath; //yourpath is a string involving something.php
    } else {
        alert(message);
    }
}
```

And change your PHP to something like:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($count==0) {
    echo "Login Failed: Please Try Again";
} else if ($count==1) {
    echo "success";
}
```

When you manage to make this work, you should fix other issues as well, namely:

- your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), therefore your site can easily be hacked
- you did not encrypt the password, which is a security leak

Comment: This code is not working.The problem remains still same.

Comment: Try to integrate it successfully.